# For any $x$ there exist a set $X$ such that $X=\{x\}$

Tags: set-theory

Clearly for the **Pair Axiom** for any $x,y$ there esist a set $X$ such that $X=\{x,y\}$ and so for any $x$ there exist a set $X$ such that $X=\{x,x\}$. Unfortunately how prove that $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$? Indeed clearly if $\{x\}$ is a set the statement is trivially true, but unfortunately I don't know if $\{x\}$ is a set: anyway I'm sure that $x$ is the unique element of $X$! so could I **formally** conclude that $X=\{x\}$? I point out that I use **ZFC** axiomatization and I found this statement in "Introduction to Set Theory" by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech where it is written that $\{x,x\}\pmb{:=}\{x\}$, but unfortunately I doubt about the strictness of this definition respect **ZFC**. So could someone help me? I know that the question could seem trivially; but if we have a carefully inspection then it seems insidious.

Comment: I am not familiar with what you start from, but why isn't {x} a set?  What do you have for the definition of a set?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I use the **ZFC** axiomatization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your version of axiomatic set theory defines sets implicitly as the objects produced by applying the axioms.  So...

- The empty set, $\varnothing$, is a set by the empty set axiom.
- The powerset of $\varnothing$, which is $\{\varnothing\}$ establishes the existence of a one element set.
- For the $x$ in your $X = \{x,x\}$, construct the functional predicate $f_x$ by the relation $\{\varnothing \mapsto x\}$, then use the axiom of replacement to obtain $\{x\}$.

This establishes that $\{x\}$ is a set for any  $x$.

For the equality $\{x\} = \{x,x\}$, use the axiom of extensionality.  Every element of $\{x\}$ is an element of $\{x,x\}$ by an exhaustive check of one element.  Every element of $\{x,x\}$ is an element of $\{x\}$ by an exhaustive check of two elements.  Therefore, the equality holds.

Comment: I don't understand the functional predicate $f_x$ so could you explain better? Anyway if I use the **Replacement Axiom** I can say that if $\pmb{P}(x,y)$ is the property $y=x$ then for any  $y\in X:=\{x,x\}$ there exist a set $Y$ such that $x\in Y$ iff $P(x,y)$ is true: so how to prove that $Y\equiv\{x\}$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro : You don't *prove* the relation, you define one.  This relation has only the one pairing $f_x(\varnothing) = x$.

Comment: Okay, so how does it use through the **Replacement Axiom**?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro : First, you are going to have to learn how to translate among common syntaces if you intend to communicate with human beings who are not looking at exactly the same text you are looking at.  Second, You have been told twice what element pairings are in the functional predicate.  $\varnothing$ is paired with $x$.  If you need to more carefully translate that into the language of your text, then *you* need to perform that translation.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I understood your functional predicate $f_x$ is my property $\pmb{P}$, right? Excuse me, forgive my confusion.

Comment: Nice answer, but why use replacement when pairing suffices?

Comment: @AlexKruckman : As OP writes: pairing gives the syntactic object "$\{x,x\}$".  It does not give the syntactic object "$\{x\}$", so is not a proof that the latter object denotes a set.  Until the latter object is a set, extensionality cannot be applied.

Comment: Pairing does not give any "syntactic object". It's an axiom of set theory that asserts the existence of a particular set. If you apply the axiom of pairing to $x$ and $x$, you get a set containing exactly one element: $x$. Do you really believe replacement is necessary to prove the existence of this set?

Comment: @AlexKruckman : I don't believe that you and OP are working from the same formalization.  Otherwise OP would never have asked the question.  I do believe that OP needs proof of the existence of a one element set that he will believe.

Comment: @EricTowers I didn't need of the proof of the existence of one element set: clearly $\{x,x\}$ has one element; instead I needed to prove that it is possible to write a singleton using the symbol $\{x\}$, that's all.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro : The words "unfortunately I don't know if {x} is a set" are exactly incompatible with what you have written in your comment.

Comment: @EricTowers Clerarly if $\{x\}$ is a set then for the **Extension Axiom** $\{x\}=\{x,x\}$, but unfortunately I was not sure that $\{x\}$ was really a set in **ZFC**, that's all. Anyway excuse me if I could write better.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro : Which is exactly why I gave you a proof in ZF showing that the singleton in the Question *is* a set.  The accepted answer (formally invalidly) applies Extension to objects defined by expressions in the underlying logic, without first verifying that the one of those objects denoted by "$\{x\}$" in your Question actually is a set.  In particular, in a finitary logic, that Answer's expression is equivalent to Extension for finite sets, is not proven to be so, and cannot be extended to infinite sets as is.

Comment: @EricTowers I recommend you pick up a textbook on ZFC set theory (Hrabacek and Jech is a good choice) before you start calling other people's answers "formally invalid". Your last sentence is totally bewildering - what does this have to do with infinite sets, or whether our logic is finitary?

Comment: @EricTowers Okay, I understand what you want mean: probably we tangled ourselves around the sense of the formal symbol $\{\quad\}$. Actually the text I mentioned adopt as convention, that $\{x\}:=\{x,x\}$ and so I wanted understand if this convention was consistent with **ZFC** formalism. So Alex showed surely that this is logically consistent, explaining that the symbol $\{\quad\}$ is actually an elucidation of the real formalism of **ZFC** to symbolize a set through its elements.

Comment: Conversely (if I have well  understood) you directely use the symbol $\{\quad\}$ to represent a set. However to accept your answer I have to undestand how to use the relation $f_x$ and the **Replacement Axiom** to prove the statement. So could you explain better, please? As reference here the **Replacement Axiom** as presented in my text. Let $\pmb{P}(x,y)$ be a property such that for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ for which $\pmb{P}(x,y)$ holds. For every set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that, for every $x\in A$ there is $y\in B$ for which $\pmb{P}(x,y)$ holds.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro : As repeatedly indicated, the $P$ in use is "only $P(\varnothing, x)$ holds".  $A = \{\varnothing\}$ and the axiom then asserts the existence of $B= \{x\}$.

Comment: Okay, all clear. Thanks too much for your clarification! Nice to meet you: I'm autodidact therefore your answer is well-recived. I hope in the future I can ask your assistance in another question. See you next time!

Answer (score 3):

What does $X = \{x\}$ mean? It means that (1) $x$ is an element of $X$, and every element of $X$ is equal to $x$.

By the Pair axiom, there exists a set $\{x,x\}$. What does this mean? It means that (2) $x$ is an element of $X$, $x$ is an element of $X$, and every element of $X$ is equal to $x$ or equal to $x$.

But (1) and (2) are equivalent, just by basic logic.

---

Let me try to clarify what I wrote above. You want to prove that $\{x\} = \{x,x\}$. This is immediate from the axiom of extensionality. To prove that $X = Y$, we just need to prove that every element of $X = \{x\}$ is an element of $Y = \{x,x\}$ and vice versa. Well, let $a\in X$. Than $a = x$. So $a\in Y$. Conversely, let $a\in Y$. Then $a = x$ or $a = x$. In either case, $a\in X$. So we're done.

---

Now for a more formal answer. The language of set theory, in which ZFC is axiomatized, does not contain the symbols $\{$ and $\}$. We use these symbols when we talk *informally* about set theory. When we write $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, we mean a set which contains the elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and no others.

In ZFC, we can express the *informal* statement $X = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ with the following formula: $$\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n a_i\in X\right) \land \forall y\, \left(y\in x\rightarrow \bigvee_{i=1}^n y = a_i\right).$$ This says that each $a_i$ is an element of $X$, and every element of $X$ is equal to one of the $a_i$.

So the formula defining $\{x\}$ (and corresponding to my condition (1) above) is $\varphi(X):$ $$x\in X\land \forall y\, (y\in X\rightarrow y = x).$$

And the formula defining $\{x,x\}$ (and corresponding to my condition (2) above) is $\psi(X)$: $$x\in X\land x\in X \land \forall y\, (y\in X\rightarrow (y = x\lor y = x)).$$

But these are logically equivalent formulas!  That is, $\forall X\, (\varphi(X)\leftrightarrow \psi(X))$.

You ask whether we can prove that $\{x\} = \{x,x\}$. This means proving $\forall X\forall Y\, (\varphi(X)\land \psi(Y)\rightarrow X = Y)$. Yes, you can prove this in ZFC using the axiom of extensionality, as I explained above.

Comment: Okay, so you claim that using **ZFC** is not possible  to conclude that $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$, or rather is necessary to use the basic logic, right? This is what I want understand.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro what? Of course you can prove this I'm ZFC. Proofs in ZFC use first-order logic (which is what I meant by basic logic).

Comment: So you claim that in **ZFC** to prove this is sufficent use the first-order logic, right? But is this was true for sake of completeness does I must prove that it is not possible to argue that $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say with your comment. But I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: All clear, thanks too much!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simplification of Alex Kruckman's answer.

$\{ \}$ is a *defined* symbol, it is not a primitive of the language of *ZFC*, [if it was a primitive of the language, then your question stands correct!] and the definition of it is as:

$x=\{a_1,..,a_n\} \equiv_{df} \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y=a_1 \lor ..\lor y=a_n)$

Now for the case of pairing we have ZFC having the axiom of pairing:

$\forall a \forall b \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y=a \lor y=b)$

Now lets substitute $a$ instead of $b$, then we'll have:

$\forall a \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y=a \lor y=a)$

So by definition of $\{\}$ we have: $\forall a \exists x (x=\{a,a\})$

But logically $y=a \lor y=a \leftrightarrow y=a$

So ZFC proves:

$\forall a \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y=a)$

and by definition of $\{\}$ this leads to ZFC proving:

$\forall a \exists x (x=\{a\})$.

And clearly by Extensionality $\{a\}=\{a,a\}$

Answer (score 0):

A set can be defined in three ways

By extension $\{...\}$

$\{x\}$ is a set with single element.

By comprehension $\{x\in .. : ...\}$

By a Venn diagram.

on the other hand, an object of the set theory, can be seen as a set or an element.

$\{x,y\}$ is set.

$y$ is an element.

$y\cup \{\{y,x)\} $  is a set.